# Script to find a folder in registry

Tags: configuration, command-line, registry

HI Guys,
I am new to scripting.
I want to write  a script to find whether that folder exists in registry or not.

Comment: Any script? Or do you have something specific in mind? What scripting language/tool do you wish to use?

Comment: just a command line for registry query

Comment: I have installed a software which created a folder in registry.I want to check whether that folder exists in registry or not.

Answer (score 0):

See [this forum thread.](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread61011.html)

> I need to check if registry value exists from within .bat ('batch') file, and it seem to be quite hard to do - not many ideas on it I have found. Maybe you can help?